# How to select more than one database tables using one query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I want to displaying the value from more than one database mysql tables.

I have code like this :

```
$db1 = "SELECT * FROM db1 where no='1' ";
$db2 = "SELECT * FROM db2 where no='1' ";
$db3 = "SELECT * FROM db3 where no='1' ";
```

and I want to use one query like this :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, $db1);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
   {
    bla bla bla...       
   }
```

is this possible if I used one query like that or there is any query to get example 3 database tables into one query? Thanks.

Comment: Need to see your db structure .

Comment: Nope you can not get data from multiple tables without performing a join on them.

Comment: Are these tables identical? The result of a select is 'tabular' - it has columns and rows. If for example table1 has different columns to table2, how do you want to combine them? What you want is possible but it's not possible to explain how to do it unless you provide info on how you want to combine the three tables? If they have identical columns, the simplest solution is `UNION ALL`, provided mysqli supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can not get data from multiple tables using one sql query without performing a join on them.

But you can use mysqli_multi_query to execute multiple queries.

Please check https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp

Comment: So, what should I used to display my database data using one query?

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp, I updated my answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have three different databases in the same server. 
In this case, you can write the query in the below format
 **Database.Schema.Table**
So in your case

`$db1 = "SELECT * FROM Database.Schema.db1 where no='1' ";

$db2 = "SELECT * FROM Database.Schema.db2 where no='1' ";

$db3 = "SELECT * FROM Database.Schema.db3 where no='1' ";`

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: I don't get it. how to use the mysqli_query based on that 3 database select?